# German listening help request: I've boiled you an egg

Tags: listening-comprehension

I am trying to improve my German listening by translating films and there is a phrase in Der Vorleser I cannot understand.

Here is a video link:

https://youtu.be/aFKiYvpM_Tk

I have:

**Ich habe dich ein Ei gekocht.  Sie steuer, wenn ich ein Ei kochen, wenn ich sie nicht sehen wollte.**

That isn't right.

Comment: Why don't you simply activate the subtitles?

Comment: Hi Bjorn, for some reason, the German subtitles for the film are different to the speech in the film.  The film subtitles are more concise.

Comment: Transcript from Youtube's algorithm: "ich habe dir ein Ei gekocht siehst du ich würde dir wohl kaum ein Ei kochen wenn ich dich nicht sehen wollte ähm Tee oder Kaffee" That's perfect except for punctuation and capitalization.

Comment: @Björn Friedrich - YouTube often uses AI to generate subtitles, and AI makes lots of mistakes in this case. I don't know if it does much better in English. Apparently AI has a hard time turning a string of words into sentences with proper periods and commas. In any case, you shouldn't be trying to get every word with listening practice; just try to pick out words you do know, figure out some from context and don't worry about the rest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Ich hab dir ein Ei gekocht, siehst du? Ich würde dir wohl kaum ein Ei kochen, wenn ich dich nicht sehen wollte. Ähm, Tee oder Kaffee?"

translated: "I've boiled an egg for you, you see? I would hardly boil an egg for you if I did not want to see you. Uh, tea or coffee?"

Comment: Danke schön, Herr Wonderbear!